# Can I execute sql select statement in if clause of sql sp

Tags: sql, asp.net

Here is my sp.Here I passing 2 parameter @diff and @id.I want to fetch data only 
for these 2 condition

```
1 : if @diff is 1 
2 : if @diff is 0 and count(*) by passing @id is grater than 1
```

Here I have done it is working.But every time my query for count(*) get execute.I don't want like that.If first condition is true,don't execute second.Is i possible within same if block?

```
create procedure Proc_selectDetail
 @Diff int,
 @id int
 as
 begin
  declare @pid int
  set @pid = (select count(*) from tbl where id = @id)
  if((@Diff = 1) or (@Diff =  0 and @pid > 1))
  begin
      if(some con)
      if(some con)
   /// fetching data
  end
 end
```

Comment: What do you mean by second exec? Second time the sp is called or is there a loop somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create procedure Proc_selectDetail
@Diff int,
@id int
as
begin
declare @pid int
if(@Diff = 1)
    begin
     /// fetching data
    end
else
    if @Diff = 0
    begin
        set @pid = (select count(*) from tbl where id = @id)
        if @pid > 1
        begin
            /// fetching data
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: your else part will run in every case where diff!=1. It should only work when diff value is zero.

Comment: Thanks @SainPradeep, I've changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Tedo G,thanks for ur help.But I have lot of coding inside if condition block.I am modifying my code.

Answer (score 0):

> One more if needed here

```
   create procedure Proc_selectDetail
    @Diff int,
    @id int
    as
    begin
   declare @pid int
   if(@Diff !=1)  
   begin
      set @pid = (select count(*) from tbl where id = @id)
    end
    if((@Diff = 1) or (@Diff =  0 and @pid > 1))
    begin
         /// fetching data
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `select count(*) from tbl where id = @id` query to `IF`. When `@Diff = 1` is true `Count` will not execute.

Try this

```
create procedure Proc_selectDetail
 @Diff int,
 @id int
 as
 begin
  declare @pid int  
  if((@Diff = 1) or (@Diff =  0 and  (select count(*) from tbl where id = @id) > 1))
  BEGIN
      set @pid = (select count(*) from tbl where id = @id) -- You can delete this if you do not need @pid.
      if(some con)
      if(some con)
   /// fetching data
  end
 end
```